# Page shows duplicate posts everytime i click on button

Tags: jquery

I am having a strange issue with Jquery Mobile. I had created a Page which displays posts and is displaying posts correctly.

Now the issue is, whenever i click on back button and click on the posts button again, it duplicates the posts and display. The number of times i click on back button and click on post button, Posts gets duplicated accordingly and shows in multiples.

For example, i have a post that is being displayed. Now i click on back button and then click on show posts button, this time, the same post displays twice. Now again if i click back button and then click on show posts button, it now the same post shows thrice and so on.

But if i refresh the page after every back button click, then it shows the posts correctly. Can anyone guide me where i am going wrong?

Here is the Code:

HTML PAGE:

```
<div data-role="page" id="userpost">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a class="back" class="button button-clear" data-rel="back" data-icon="back" href="#">back</a>
        <p style="text-align: center">Posts History</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p id="username"></p>
        <div class="row cf" id="userPosts">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h6>&copy;</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
function displayuserPosts() {
    if (localStorage.login = "true") {
        var username = localStorage.username;
        $('#username').append("<p style='font-size:10px; color:red; text-align:center;'>Welcome: " + username + "</p>");
        var userPosts = "username=" + username + "&upost";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../php-code2/uposts.php",
            data: userPosts,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                    $("#userPosts").append('<p class="job cf">'+ field.title +'</p>');
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please login to post a Job");
        window.location.href = "#Main";
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help much without the code you made so far

Comment: Updated with Code now. Through this code, i am very well able to display Post Title on the page. But The issue starts once i click on back button and then tries to click on Posts Button. Then it duplicates the same content and displays twice. This scenario grows by the number of times, i click on post button. But if i refresh the page, then it displays normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
$("#userPosts").append('<p class="job cf">'+ field.title +'</p>');
```

Change `.append` to `.html`.

"append" means add content to what is already in the element ( `#userPosts` in this case).
;)

---

**EDIT**

Okay. Let's try something else then.
You already use localstorage...

Why not set a boolean flag when posts are loaded?
And one date flag to know when it was loaded...

What I call a flag is a variable used only to remember a state... To be used in comparisons.

So this should work.
Notice you can use a [more precise time](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to remember.

```
// It good to know todays date.
var today = new Date().getDate(); // day of the month

function displayuserPosts() {

  // Executes only if logged in AND the posts not already loaded today.
  if(    localStorage.login == "true"
      && localStorage.userpostsLoaded != "true"
      && localStorage.userpostsWhen != today ){

      var username = localStorage.username;
      $('#username').append("<p style='font-size:10px; color:red; text-align:center;'>Welcome: " + username + "</p>");
      var userPosts = "username=" + username + "&upost";

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "../php-code2/uposts.php",
          data: userPosts,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                  $("#userPosts").append('<p class="job cf">'+ field.title +'</p>');
              });

              // Set some flags!
              localStorage.userpostsLoaded="true";
              localStorage.userpostsWhen=today;
          }
      });

  }else{

    // If the Ajax request was avoided because of the login
    if( localStorage.login != "true" ){
      alert("Please login to post a Job");
      window.location.href = "#Main";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That would not suffice my requirement. Because, i am looping the content in the element which mean i need to display multiple results. But when i change to .html, it displays only one result inteasd all. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks Louys for your reply. I solved this in another way. I just added $('#userPosts').html('');  at the start of function after login credentials which ensures that the element is empty before loading and is working fine now :-). Though Accepted your answer. :-). Thanks!